# how to remove "L" from "HELLO" string and put a space in it's position

Tags: c#, string

i want to remove "L" from "HELLO" string and put a space in it's position so string will become "HE LO" but the problem is that it remove the whole string not just "L"

```
namespace 10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
            this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
            this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        string s;

        Font fn;

        SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

        int x, y, st = 15, f = 0, count = 0;

        Bitmap B;

        char ptrav;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            B = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);

            x = this.Width / 2;
            y = this.Height / 2;

        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawDBuff(e.Graphics);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                f = 2;
                s = "اهلا";
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                f = 1;
                s = "HELLO";
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                st += 5;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                st -= 5;
            }


            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                if (f == 1 || f == 2)
                {
                    f = 3;
                }
            }

            DrawDBuff(this.CreateGraphics());
        }

        void DrawDBuff(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(B);
            DrawScene(g2);
            g.DrawImage(B, 0, 0);
        }

        void DrawScene(Graphics g)
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Gray);

            if (f == 1)
            {
                fn = new Font("Times New Roman", st);
                g.DrawString(s, fn, b, x, y);
            }

            if (f == 2)
            {
                fn = new Font("Times New Roman", st);
                g.DrawString(s, fn, b, x, y);
            }

            if (f == 3)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    ptrav = s[i];

                    if (ptrav == 'L')
                    {
                        count++;

                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                          s=  s.Replace("L", " ");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This totally looks like C#

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] (with emphasis on *minimal*)

Comment: When f==3 you are not calling the g.Drawstring so you are left with an empty image

Comment: Why assign "HELLO" first and then change it to "HE LO" later? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @ThomasWeller i am just messing around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the value of f is 3 there is no call to g.Drawstring so you are left with an empty image. However the code still have problems with the way in which you remove the letter L with Replace. This will remove all letter L from HELLO

```
void DrawScene(Graphics g)
{
    // Clear the screen
    g.Clear(Color.Gray);

    if (f == 1)
        fn = new Font("Times New Roman", st);

    else if (f == 2)
        fn = new Font("Times New Roman", st);
    else if (f == 3)
        s = s.Replace("LL", " L");

    // Draw whatever string is in s with the current font 
    g.DrawString(s, fn, b, x, y);
}
```

Also keep in mind that objects like Font, SolidBrush are disposable and you shouldn't create them at each step without disposing the previous instances. This will consume your system resources very fast.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression together with a call to [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys(v=vs.110).aspx) can do the trick here:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("L"));

String text = "HELLO";
String textModified = regex.Replace(text, " ", 1);

Console.WriteLine(textModified);
```

This outputs `HE LO`. You can apply this logic to your current code to obtain the desired result.

Alternatively, if you want to obtain the same result without using regular expression, you can use the following approach which relys on [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
String text = "HELLO";

Int32 idx = text.IndexOf("L");
String textFixed = text.Substring(0, idx) + " " + text.Substring(idx + 1);

Console.WriteLine(textModified);
```

Comment: Alternatively for no regex, `.Remove(...).Insert(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this like so:

```
var text = "HELLO";    
String.Concat(text.Split('L').Select(s => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? " L" : s));
```

Really depends on what condition you are looking for.

Comment: Why not `s="HE LO";`?